# overlay on glyphicons when hover

Tags: html, css, overlay, navbar, glyphicons

Hi i have a navbar in my website. its display inline. At the moment the navbar consits of glyphicons and next to them the "describtion" in text. (for exaple "back" or "settings")
I like to have only the glyphicons and when the mouse is over one there should come an overlay (a little bigger then the size of the glyphicon) slightly colored and with the words of the text.
How can I do that? I already tried multiple tutorials online, but they didn't work with the inline order of the glyphicons...

```css
#admin_menu .glyphicon                                  { margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; font-size: 25px;}
#admin_menu                                             { text-align: left; list-style-type: none; margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px; padding: 0px; }
#admin_menu li                                          { display: inline; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; }
#admin_menu li a                                        { background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px; }
```

```html
<ul id="admin_menu">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span>  <span> text </span> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <span> text </span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> <span> text </span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <span> text </span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> <span> text </span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span> <span> text </span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Qverlays will require absolute positioning, I'd start there.

Comment: i already tried something with absoulte positioning, but then I run into the problem, that I can't vertacially align the text to middle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/d04pLr6q/

This may not be what you wanted to achieve, not sure ;)

```
   #admin_menu .glyphicon{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 24px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12px;
    top: 8px;
    }
    #admin_menu { text-align: left; list-style-type: none; margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px; padding: 0px; }
    #admin_menu li{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    }
    #admin_menu li a { 
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    height:40px;
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
     }
     #admin_menu .description{
       color:transparent;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height:100%;
       top: 0;
       left:0;
       text-align: center;
       line-height: 40px;
       display: block;
       transition: all 0.3s;
     }
    #admin_menu li a:hover .description{
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(51, 122, 183, 0.75);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something like what you are after:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#admin_menu .glyphicon {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 15px
}
#admin_menu {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#admin_menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#admin_menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#admin_menu li a span:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}
#admin_menu li a:hover .glyphicon {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}
#admin_menu li a:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="admin_menu">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span>  <span> text </span> </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <span> text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> <span> text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <span> text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></span> <span> text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span> <span> text </span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```